# Using jQuery to append content from sibling

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this html on my page:

```
<div class='item'>
    <h2><a href='http://www.mysite.com/1'>Link 1</a></h2>
    <p class='desc'>Text text text text</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
    <h2><a href='http://www.mysite.com/2'>Link 2</a></h2>
    <p class='desc'>Text text text text</p>
</div>

<div class='item'>
    <h2><a href='http://www.mysite.com/3'>Link 3</a></h2>
    <p class='desc'>Text text text text</p>
</div>
```

I want to append a link to the end of the paragraph, using the link from the sibling h2 tag. I have this jQuery:

```
$('p.desc').append(' <a href="' + $(this).prev().find('a').attr('href') + '">More ></a>');
```

But the link is just set to `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have an unneeded ">" to the right of "More".

Comment: @Swordfish0321: Don't think it's unneeded, just meant to be an arrow for 'More', he should probably make it [`&gt;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2) though.

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino Yeah, I caught that after commented, but I left for posterity, because I think a special char should be used as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to get a value relative to each element and then create an anchor tag you can't simply chain the operation like you have. There needs to be some sort of iteration done so you can then scope each specific paragraph and get the relative link. Most of the time you could use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for this, but [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html) happens to support a function as its argument, which then needs to return what you will be adding to each element. Within this context you can then resolve what the h2's link is and return the new anchor.

```
$('p.desc').append(function() { // loop through all p.desc and add something
    // within this function, $(this) is now the current p.desc
    var link = $(this).prev('h2').find('a').attr('href'); // get the path
    return $('<a/>').attr('href', link).text('More'); // return the new link
});
```

You could obviously not bother creating the `link` variable, I just hate long lines of code and think this way it is a lot easier to make out what is going on.

Comment: You should explain the difference between `this` in the OP's example ( `$('p.desc').append()`) and yours (within `$.each()`). That should clarify the fact that you need to deal with each paragraph independently

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yeah, I was actually on my way out of the office when I answered it so I didn't go into details.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.desc').append(function(
    return $(this).prev('h2').find('a').clone().text('More >');
});
```

Comment: +1, totally forgot about append being able to accept a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `$(this)`, it's not applying scope the way you intended because you are passing it as an argument to the append method essentially nesting your scope where there are no anchor tags--hence you getting the undesired result of "undefined". By using "each" you can properly assign scope with the current code you are using, just wrap it in an anonymous function like so:

```
$('p.desc').each(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```